# combine jquery and jQuery(document).ready(function(){ in a single js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I would like to ask, is it possible to combine the

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$j('#featured-products').jcarousel();
$j("a.group").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'pp_default',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: true});
    $j('#slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed:  '1000',
        timeout: 3500,
    pager:  '#slidernav' 
    }); 
    $j("#slider").mouseover(function() {
            $j('#slider').cycle('pause');
    }).mouseout(function(){
            $j('#slider').cycle('resume');
    });
});
```

in the same js file [at the end] that is made up of varied jquery plugins.

Would appreciate all the help of how to accomplish such.

With best regards

Fabian

Comment: Sure, it should be easy to combine files on the server side. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day... jQuery or not, plugin or not.. it's all just JavaScript.  So you can throw every little bit of JavaScript in a single file and there shouldn't be any problems (except readability, maintainability, lack of separation of concerns, etc).

Comment: Thanks Felix and Kon, I am faced with a situation to try and optimize an existing site [one page template] that has over 20 js and css calls and multiple html inline js script calls. How would I accomplish that as when I tried nothing happen...

Comment: Have you looked into JS minification?  If not, check out:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/  
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html  
http://www.minifyjs.com/

Comment: Yeap, I have used the minified versions of all the plugins, combined them into one, now I need to know how to make it all work by passing the varied commands into the same js file. The site is also running prototype, hence I need to pass the jquery noconflict as well.

Comment: Sounds like a poorly designed site/page.  Might want to consider a redesign.  :)

Comment: Yeap that's my mission and would also like to change scripts form using the existing prototype to jquery so I would use just one framework. Yet I have no idea where to start...